# What are the differences between Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomTaskPane and Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane..?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I'm creating my first VSTO add-in for Microsoft Office, and just I realized there are two types for CustomTaskPane, and I got them crossed:

```
Imports Core = Microsoft.Office.Core   'Version 12
Imports Tools = Microsoft.Office.Tools 'Version 9
```

What are the differences..?

I understand they're in different libraries, but I was wondering what else might be different. If I look in Object Browser, the Tools version has some additional methods and functions, but otherwise seems the same. I cannot remove the Office reference, since I'm using members from it which do not exists in Tools.

They *seem* to be the same type, but looking at the Base Types, the Tools version makes no references to the Core version. I inadvertently crossed the two versions in my code, and it still worked. But since this is a VSTO add-in, it seems prudent to clean up the code and stick with the Tools version.

Can someone with more experience shed some light on this..?

Comment: Did the contribution below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the `Tools` version provides expanded functionality. There are a large number of `Tools` objects of this type, not all provide expanded functionality, however.

VSTO "wraps" objects provided by Office COM libraries so that they can be used more "natively" by the .NET Framework and, in special instances, provide additional, useful functionality not provided by the COM libraries.

As long as you don't want to use any of the expanded functionality, in theory it doesn't matter whether you use the `Tools` or COM `Interop` namespace. In practise, using the original COM version can be faster in execution.

Personally, my preference is to consistently work with the COM `Interop` objects unless I specifically want to work with functionality provided by the `Tools`.

In the case of Custom Task Panes, however, you *should* use the `Tools` namespace. This has been optimized to work with Windows Forms and WPF controls and generally integrate with .NET Framework code.

Comment: Ahhh...wrappers. Got it. My addin learning has been slow, but methodical. My goal was/is an addin for Access, even knowing it has no built-in application events. The first one I created with the Shared COM Addin wizard, and slowly & tediously tweaked it to get a working foundation. But I couldn't get an Access application reference to the currently running host instance; only `"New"` ones. Then I found this amazing page... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/02/19/vsto-add-ins-for-access/ [Cont'd]

Comment: Regarding the above link, basically you start with a VSTO addin for Word, then use Notepad to replace every instance of `Word` with `Access` in the `*.vbproj` file and all the `*.vb` files and everything else. There are other bits to tweak, but it actually works..! I now have *a working VSTO addin for Access*..! But of course...still minus the app events, but I'm working on that. It gave me the host app reference I needed: `Dim app As Access.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`. My next exploration is to reverse engineer `ThisAddin.*` files to see how it's done and make it COM-only.

Comment: Yes, @spinjector, Andrew Whitechapel was ***the*** VSTO .NET<->COM guru. His blog articles are worth diamonds and I hope they never disappear...

Comment: Yes, from what I've seen so far he's like the Chip Pearson of VSTO.